convergence in probability of transformed poisson variables
Let $(S_n)$ be independent Poisson variables with parameter $\lambda = 5n$. Determine if the following sequence converges in distribution, and if so, find the limit: $Y_n := \sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{5n}$
My idea was to check the pointwise limit of characteristic function $\phi_{Y_n}(t)$ but I'm having trouble transforming $\phi_{S_n}(t)$ accordingly.

The easiest way to approach this problem I know is to realize additive property of Poisson distribution.
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim Poisson(5)$, then $S_n\overset{d}{=}X_1+\dots+X_n\sim Poisson(5n)$. By Central Limit Theorem,
$$
\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}S_n-5)\overset{d}{\to} Normal(0,5)
$$
Use Delta Method with $g(a)=\sqrt{a}$, and $g'(a)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}$, then
$$
\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{\frac{S_n}{n}}-\sqrt{5})\overset{d}{\to} Normal(0,\frac{1}{4})
$$
which is,
$$
\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{5n} \overset{d}{\to} Normal(0,\frac{1}{4})
$$
Q.E.D.
